# How to remove sidebar search from VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I remove this search feature? Its ruining all my keyboard shortcuts!

[image]

Comment: I find this feature quite annoying too, and I'm surprised that there doesn't appear to be an answer anywhere.

Comment: The biggest problem I've noticed is that it seems to focus itself after some async actions (like adding a file to git), so if you e.g. move focus to a text file while the file is adding to git and start typing, you then start searching instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From vscode [1.32.0](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_32#_automatic-keyboard-navigation-setting):

```json
"workbench.list.automaticKeyboardNavigation": false,
```

---

Command id that temporarily toggles it back:

`list.toggleKeyboardNavigation`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a valid setting anymore, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Add `"workbench.list.keyboardNavigation": "simple"` to your VSCode settings

1. In the editor press: `Ctrl` + `shift` + `p`
2. Type: **settings**
3. Click on: **Preferences: Open settings (JSON)**
4. Add the following line: `"workbench.list.keyboardNavigation": "simple"`